# How to use Java Regular Expressions to extract the following data?

Tags: java, regex, hadoop, apache-pig

How to obtain the first long number from the whole sentence given below using regular exression:

```
396124450036269056,"@Anyi1987 asi fue,bano total para mi.,:D",MiriamBustam
```

I want the result as: 396124450036269056.
So how do I represent the number in this whole sentence using regular expressions?
I am using Apache Pig scripting language which makes use of Java regular expressions. 
So in Apace Pig:

REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL:
Syntax:
REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL (string, regex)
. Use the REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL function to perform regular expression matching and to extract all matched groups.

```
This example will return the tuple (192.168.1.5,8020).

REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL('192.168.1.5:8020', '(.*)\:(.*)');
```

REGEX_EXTRACT:

Syntax:
REGEX_EXTRACT (string, regex, index).
Use the REGEX_EXTRACT function to perform regular expression matching and to extract the matched group defined by the index parameter (where the index is a 1-based parameter.)

```
This example will return the string '192.168.1.5'.

REGEX_EXTRACT('192.168.1.5:8020', '(.*):(.*)', 1);
```

Comment: Do you really need a regex? `s.substring(0, s.indexOf(","))` is more than enough. if yes, `\d+` must work.

Comment: try `s.split(",")[0]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Regex in Pig in hadoop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089571/using-regex-in-pig-in-hadoop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d+`

Matches all digit characters.

So it matches `396124450036269056` in this case.

You don't need a regex here. You could use a `substring()`.

```
s.substring(0, s.indexOf(","))
```

Comment: Regarding substring, I suspect It would have to in some way use Apache Pig, I think, not just basic java constructs (see http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/SUBSTRING.html)

Comment: Oh I see, then the regex would help :)

Comment: For now the following code works:
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(SUBSTRING(line,0,18))  AS (tweetid:long);
But the reason why we are using delimiter is because the length of the number can vary. And in Pig the Regex code extracts the code represented by (.*)  

The following code works :
REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*)[,”:-](.*)[“,:-](.*)'))  AS (tweetid:long,msg:chararray,userid:chararray);
But I cant understand how it works?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know that language. If the length of the numbers is a constant, you could do so. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think is not exist a regular expresion to match the longest number from a text. 
The expressions like \d+ or \d* will match only the first number no matter how many digits will have. So if you will have "55  msadmmsada 8882138213821321382183" those expressions will match 55 only.

Answer (score 0):

If your string always starts with a number, simply use `(\d+)` [(see this at regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/eV2sV5/2).

This will extract all digits at the start of something into a matching group. So, if I understand your examples right,

```
REGEX_EXTRACT(you, '(\d+).*', 1);
```

Would do the trick. You would only have to append the `.*` if this function has to match the whole text to extract something, otherwise you can omit it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
\d*
```

and it will match 396124450036269056

> **Explanation**:
>
> \d* match a digit [0-9]
>
> Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times