# How does the following code in Pig (in hadoop ) work using Java regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a CSV file containing the following data:

```
396124436476092000,Think about the life you livin but don't think so hard it hurts Life is truly a gift, but at the same it is a curse,Obey_Jony09
396124436740317184,"“@BleacherReport: Halloween has given us this amazing Derrick Rose photo (via @amandakaschube, @ScottStrazzante) http://t.co/tM0wEugZR1” yes",Colten_stamkos
```

I have written the following code in PigLatin to input data to alias B using delimiters in REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL. This command outputs all data represented by (.*)

```
A = load '/user/pig/tweets' as (line);

B = FOREACH A  GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*)[,”:-](.*)[“,:-](.*)'))  AS (tweetid:long,msg:chararray,userid:chararray);
```

So want to know how the regex function works with the expression

```
'(.*)[,”:-](.*)[“,:-](.*)'
```

to split data into the schema (tweetid,msg,userid)

Comment: You have asked the same question three times in 2 hours...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Regex in Pig in hadoop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089571/using-regex-in-pig-in-hadoop)